# Vim auto indent for lines below a parenthesis

Tags: vim

I want the Vim indentation to start the cursor right below the first character inside my openinng parenthesis, like in the below code, the 'start' is right below the 'first'. How can I do that? I have been googling about this but didn't get the exact answer I wanted. I have autoindent and smart indent ON in my vimrc. Please note that this is for C-style languages. Thanks

```
function_name(first, has, way, too, many, arguments, to, fit,
              start, one, line);
```

Comment: Stop googling and start reading "help" instead:  `:h cinoptions-values` and `:h cino-(` particularly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can work in your case.

`:set cino=(0`

As Matt said, pleaser refer to `:h cinoptions-values`